# how to zoom layout with respect to a certain point

Tags: android, animation, zooming, scale

I want to zoom a layout [this(Popup)](http://www.ui-transitions.com/#categories) and what I tried is:

```
ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setStartOffset(6000);
                trylayout.startAnimation(animation);
```

and this

```
ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
        // /start animation on egg image
        One.startAnimation(scale);
        scale.setDuration(100);
    //  scale.setFillAfter(true);
        scale.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

But not able to get it, how can I zoom as in the link, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setPivotX` and `setPivotY`.

> You can specify the center point of the image from which it grows
>   outward (or inward) by specifying pivotX and pivotY. For example, if
>   these values are 0, 0 (top-left corner), all growth will be down and
>   to the right.

[Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: but pivorX,Y are working for zooming w r t a point like topleftas I tried this                                                                      ScaleAnimation scaleExpand = new ScaleAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f,pivotX,pivotY);